# Javascript Timed My Function

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Can anyone help me with errors that I'm getting when trying to add to my timed my function (). What I'm trying to do is delay 10 seconds before video ads show. The page I'm showing is loaded into a php system that includes header footer etc.

Here is my code im currently using :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.optimalupload.com/upload/download/advertisement.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#tester {
    display:none;
}
--
</style>

<script language="javascript">
var max_time = 10;
var cinterval ;

function countdown_timer(){
  // decrease timer
  max_time--;
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = max_time;
  if(max_time == 0){
    clearInterval(cinterval);
  }
}
// 1,000 means 1 second.
cinterval = setInterval('countdown_timer()', 1000);
</script>

<div class="contentPageWrapper">
    <div class="pageSectionMainFull ui-corner-all">
        <div class="pageSectionMainInternal">


<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById("tester") != undefined)
{document.write('<p class="no"> Video beings in <strong><span id="countdown">10</span></strong> seconds. We have detected that you are not using <strong>AdBlock</strong> or some other adblocking software. Your pre-download advertisment video will being shortly.<!-- end .content --></p>');window.setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction();    
  }, 10000);
}
else
{
document.write('<p class="no"> Ads displayed in <strong><span id="countdown">10</span></strong> seconds. We have detected that you are using <strong>AdBlock</strong> or some other adblocking software. You will be using our affliate download page. If you would rather use our default video ad page please refresh with adblock disabled. To download your file simply take a look at our partners below. The download link to your file is embedded into one of the advertisments.<!-- end .content --></p>');window.setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction();        
    }, 10000);
}
</script>
```

Then I'm trying to define myFunction(); as this:

I do it like this.

```
function myFunction() {
<script src="(Link to video ad stream/ Not in directory)" type="text/javascript"></script><noscript><iframe src="(Link to stream with no javascript" scrolling="no" framborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="width:1px;height:1px;display:none;"></iframe></noscript>
}
```

However nothing works. The timer still goes off after counting down but nothing is loading. Is there another way to code this system?

Comment: What are the errors you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Display the ad when the timer reaches zero:

```
function countdown_timer(){
  // decrease timer
  max_time--;
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = max_time;
  if(max_time == 0){
    clearInterval(cinterval);
    display_ad();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is simple: To time the trigger of a javascript function, you just have to do something like this:

```
setTimeout("alert('hi!');", 500);
```

And you can do other custom functions instead of that alert, i just put it there for you to test.

SetInterval runs it every 10 seconds, the setTimeout just runs it once - i believe that is what you need?

As for your countdown, your approach is fairly ok, but you should so a setInterval with 1 second, and each time it runs, decrement the variable holding the seconds and update the html, then when the setTimeout runs (in 10s), clear the interval - or make it clear itself after the counter hits zero.

Comment: What about his countdown?

Comment: Simple... that should be a separate setInterval function, that gets cleared after the 10 seconds that pass (the setTimeout i suggested above) - hope it makes sense for him, i am editing the answer now to include this.

Answer (score -1):

To to add js dynamically use something like

```
function myFunction(){
    var g = document.createElement('script'), s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.src = 'yourjsscript.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
}
```

the `noscript` won't be able to be produced in a script tag if script is disabled so just add it as normal html to where the video will be normally shown.

```
<noscript><iframe src="(Link to stream with no javascript" scrolling="no" framborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="width:1px;height:1px;display:none;"></iframe></noscript>
```

So you'll need something like the following because the `if(document.getElementById("tester") != undefined)` will execute right a way even if you have a `setInterval` so wrap it in a function and call it after the timer has finished.

```
var max_time = 10;
var cinterval;

function countdown_timer(){
    // decrease timer
    max_time--;
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = max_time;
    if(max_time == 0){
        clearInterval(cinterval);
        showAds();
    }
}
// 1,000 means 1 second.
cinterval = setInterval('countdown_timer()', 1000);
function showAds(){
    if(document.getElementById("tester") != undefined){
        ...
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            myFunction();    
        }, 10000);
    }else{
        ...
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            myFunction();        
        }, 10000);
    }
}
function myFunction(){
    var g = document.createElement('script'), s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.src = 'yourjsscript.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
}
```

Comment: These will do the same thing.

Comment: My guess is you tested it at jsfiddle, but forgot to select one of the `No wrap` options.

Comment: If the argument to `setInterval` is a string, it will be `eval`ed when the timer fires, and it can only access global variables. If you don't use `No wrap` in jsfiddle, the code is inside an anonymous function, not in the global scope.